# Timed click link rather than timed redirect

Tags: hyperlink, click, timed

the action I need is after 1 min (and only once, not every minute), a link click is performed, opening the page. I cannot have this as a page redirect. The reason, the test page you can see below, requires a video background to not start over after the 1 minute AND the page opening with instructions to the user.

I need the action to be the same as if the user clicked the link (if they clicked the link, the page would open and the background video would not start over)

http://kartbattle.com/tester - if you click the link on the top right, the page opens but the video doesn't start over....

if you redirect to the page http://kartbattle.com/tester/?page_id=23 the video starts over which I cannot have happen.

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://kartbattle.com/tester', '_self', '', true)}, 60000);
```

EDIT:

You will still need to use javascript. First add an id attribute to your hyperlink:

```
<a id="auto-click" href="http://kartbattle.com/tester/?page_id=23">
```

then add in the following line to your onLoad handler:

```
setTimeout(document.getElementById('auto-click').click();, 60000);
```

this should achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: This seems to do the same as a page redirect. It basically opened but refreshed the entire page.

Comment: It does not matter which of URL 's above are used, the page refreshes and the video restarts - I think your problem is in your code somewhere and has nothing to do with which URL is used! See my edit above for some additional ideas.

Comment: ok, so what i need is the video to be playing.. then at 1 minute, the link (page) opens but the background video does NOT start over. If a user was on the test site, the video starts playing .. then when you click the link, the page overlays on the video. That is what i am trying to do, but have it done at a specified interval. Hope that made sense. thx

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are asking - your test site confused me with the constant refreshing every few seconds. See my further edit above for details.

Comment: ah darn, i had a meta refresh tag in there accidentally. I have removed it.

Comment: Thx FastGeek for your efforts. I am a little confused in exactly how to implement it into the wordpress structure. 'settimeout' goes in the head i assume. Where does the 'a id' go? thx

Comment: That is an entirely different question. I can't help you with WordPress - I've never used it! Basically you need to ensure that whatever hyperlink you wish to click has an id attribute so that you can reference it individually with javascript, and you will need to declare a page load event handler in which you would call the setTimeout( ... ); I would also recommend performing a URL check for the page currently loaded if you only want the automatic click action to happen on a specific page. Good luck!